# How can I add timestamps to the nested Schema in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, backend

This is how my mongoose model looks like, I have a comment Schema and it has replies field which can be an array of objects of the same type.

```
const commentSchema = new Schema({
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  likes: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  wroteBy: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  replies: [this]
}, { timestamps: true })
```

Default timestamps work fine for the main object, however comments in the replies array don't get any timestamps.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `timestamp` option also in `reply` schema definition.

```
const replySchema = new Schema({
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  likes: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  wroteBy: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
}, { timestamps: true }); // <<<--- Add timestamp to reply schema

const commentSchema = new Schema({
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  likes: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  wroteBy: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  replies: [replySchema]
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Comment: Yeah, I did it in the end as well. I just didn't want to duplicate the same kind of schema and thought there was some way to avoid it. Thank you again for your help. :)

Comment: Anytime, glad to hear it helped :)